# strace does not report creation of file

Tags: autotools, strace

Yesterday I asked a question here on how to see which files were written by an application command, and a good answer pointed me to `strace`.  I can look for `open` system calls in the output of `strace`.  This worked until today, when I tried to do this on the `./configure` command, which is part of autotools.

`./configure` definitely creates the file `Makefile`

But there is no system call in the output of

> strace -fF ./configure

that involves `Makefile`.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

I tracked this down, it is because the command involves `mv`.  In that case, there is no `open` call for the second operand.